# express --view=hbs myapp getting [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function

Tags: node.js, express, express-generator

[image]- express --view=hbs myapp
[node version 12.18.2]

Getting error like this

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function`

Answer (score 6):

Install express generator as a root
`sudo npm install -g express-generator`